# How do I merge consecutive numbers in a sorted list of numbers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, concatenation

I want to concatenate a sequence of numbers in a readable string. Consecutive numbers should be merged like this `'1-4'`.

I'm able to concatenate an array with all the numbers into a complete string but I'm having trouble combining / merging consecutive numbers.

I tried comparing the previous and next values with the current one in the loop with several `if`-conditions but I couldn't seem to find the right ones to make it work properly.

Examples:

```
if(ar[i-1] === ar[i]-1){}
if(ar[i+1] === ar[i]+1){}
```

My code looks like this:

```js
var ar = [1,2,3,4,7,8,9,13,16,17];

var pages = ar[0];
var lastValue = ar[0];

for(i=1; i < ar.length; i++){
      if(ar[i]-1 === lastValue){
          pages = pages + ' - ' + ar[i];
      }else{
          pages = pages + ', ' + ar[i];
      }
}

alert(pages);
```

Result is: `1 - 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 13, 16, 17`

In the end it should look like this: `1-4, 7-9, 13, 16-17`.

---

EDIT:
I used the first answer at @CMS' link for my Script. Looks pretty much like a shorter version of @corschdi's snippet:

```js
var ar = [1,2,3,4,7,8,9,13,16,17];


var getRanges = function(array) {
  var ranges = [], rstart, rend;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    rstart = array[i];
    rend = rstart;
    while (array[i + 1] - array[i] == 1) {
      rend = array[i + 1]; // increment the index if the numbers sequential
      i++;
    }
    ranges.push(rstart == rend ? rstart+'' : rstart + '-' + rend);
  }
  return ranges;
}


alert(getRanges(ar));
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270910/how-to-convert-sequence-of-numbers-in-an-array-to-range-of-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 13, 16, 17];

var ranges = [];
var index = 0;
while (index < array.length) {
    var rangeStartIndex = index;
    while (array[index + 1] === array[index] + 1) {
        // continue until the range ends
        index++;
    }

    if (rangeStartIndex === index) {
        ranges.push(array[index]);
    } else {
        ranges.push(array[rangeStartIndex] + " - " + array[index]);
    }
    index++;
}

console.log(ranges.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code, `lastValue` never changes in the loop, so you're forever comparing against the first element in the array. Also, when you do find a match, you aren't yet ready to append to the `pages` result just yet--there might be more numbers to come.

One approach might be to keep a run of the current sequence of numbers (or just the first and last numbers in a run), and only append this run to the result string whenever we find a break in the sequence or hit the end of the string.

There are many ways to approach this, and I recommend checking other folks' answers at the [Codewars: Range Extraction](https://www.codewars.com/kata/51ba717bb08c1cd60f00002f) kata, which is (almost) identical to this problem.

Here's my solution:

```js
const rangeify = a => {
  const res = [];
  let run = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    run.push(a[i]);

    if (i + 1 >= a.length || a[i+1] - a[i] > 1) {
      res.push(
        run.length > 1 ? `${run[0]}-${run.pop()}` : run
      );
      run = [];
    }
  }
  
  return res.join(", ");
};

[
  [1,2,3,4,7,8,9,13,16,17],
  [],
  [1],
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [1, 2, 3, 8],
  [1, 3, 4, 8],
  [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 16],
  [-9, -8, -7, -3, -1, 0, 1, 2, 42]
].forEach(test => console.log(rangeify(test)));
```

Comment: I understood the other solutions faster, as I'm fairly new to coding and didn't get '=>' and '$' yet. Thanks for the hint about Codewars. Might need to head there for some more learning.